# Virus Scan Windows 8 Bootcamp Partition from OS X?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, scanning

Is there any software I can use to scan a bootcamp partition on OSX for viruses from OS X?

I prefer to run the scan from OS X because:

- Typically Windows anti-virus solutions are more like full suites that
  require an installation. I do not wish to install anything like that
  because it would incur a performance penalty.
- As I understand it, running the scan from outside the OS you're
  scanning means that anything potentially malicious on the OS won't
  interfere with the scan.

I suppose I could use a bootdisk of some kind but that is difficult because some bootdisks are not compatible with macbooks.

So I figure if OSX is already hosting/aware of the Windows partition I should be able to easily scan it from OSX right?

Comment: ClamAV supposedly runs on OS X. I have used it from Linux to scan a Windows partition and it worked well.

Comment: @aglasser I have used clam in the past and it seemed to work fine. So that's definitely a good suggestion. The only thing I'm not sure about is how effective it is vs other projects.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. I am not sure of any good Mac solution that will have the coverage of Windows viruses that Windows tools such as Security Essentials do. ClamAV may have pretty good signatures, but I can't vouch for whether it does or does not have a comparable scan and fix ability to a commercial product. Mac virus scan programs may be better, but again, they would probably have more focus on Mac viruses.
2. By default, NTFS partitions are *not* writable on Mac OS X. You therefore could detect, but not fix or remove, viruses from your Windows partition. The only way around this is to purchase a commercial product such as Paragon NTFS, or go through some interesting challenges to get open-source drivers to mount the partition read-write.

If you use Microsoft's offline version of Security essentials (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-is-windows-defender-offline) and your Mac is reasonably new, you should be able to make a bootable USB drive that will work - just insert it and hold down Option as you power on your Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to vote for ClamXAv (http://www.clamxav.com) too. I am using this software since many years, and I am very happy with it. On 10.9 it found the Genieo software and helped me to remove it.

It would be new to me, that this great free application has a focus on Mac viruses. May be fdmillion can give us some facts?

Whether you can use it for removing viruses depends on your Mac OS system: if you are using Mac OS X 10.6 and a FAT-32 Windows partion / volume, then you scan a Win volume and remove files.

As far as I know this has changed with newer Mac / Win system: you can read Win volumes with Mac, but only read / write to Mac volumes using a Win system.
Another reason for me to stay on 10.6 and Win XP, because I prefer full access on Mac, but no access on Win.